# C# .NET to Apache Ignite on Docker

Tags: c#, docker, ignite

I am new to Apache Ignite and our requirement is to run it on docker, however, I tried searching online how to connect from my C# .NET application to the dockerize Apache Ignite but couldn't find a good resource about this.

I have a docker-compose file that contains the following:

```
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  ignite:
    image: "apacheignite/ignite:latest"
    container_name: 'test-ignite'
    ports:
      - '47100:47100'
    networks:
      - app-tier
    environment:
      IGNITE_HOST: 'test-ignite'
```

and I run docker-compose up, and Apache Ignite is running. However, I do not know how to connect from my C# code to this dockerized ignite. Please let me know how to do so and if you can give me sample code snippet then that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to connect client node or even server node, you will have to specify discovery configuration that will be able to find your dockerized node(s). Such as [TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery#section-static-ip-finder) with hostname of your dockerized Ignite. Note that all nodes in cluster need to be able to connect to Discovery and Communication ports of every other node.
- If you want to use thin client or e.g. ODBC client, just specify the hostname when connecting.

Comment: Hi alamar, I tried connecting using C# .NET Console application to the dockerized instance of Apache Ignite but I keep getting this error though "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". If possible, do you have a sample on the first item you mentioned regarding discovery configuration?

Comment: I also tried using ThinClient like the one mentioned in the sample here: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/thin-client but no luck as well.

Comment: @dellboy is it possible to collect logs from your dockerized instance during connection attempts? I'll add link to answer.

Comment: I finally get this to work but need to do changes when running docker so instead of my docker-compose, I have to run docker under network set to "host" with this command: "docker run -it --name dellboy-cache --net=host -e "IGNITE_CONFIG=sample-ignite-config.xml" apacheignite/ignite" and  on my C# code I specified TcpDiscoverySpi with the LocalAddress set my computer name and port and it got connected. However, I notice something, why is it that even if I start my ClientMode to true, it is still starting another instance of Apache Ignite before it connects to my dockerized instance?

Comment: @dellboy Client node is still a full Apache Ignite node, the differences with Server Node are minor: it does not participate in discovery ring and does not store data by default.

Comment: I see but if I want a web service to write into the Apache Ignite node cache, what would be the best way to do this? Because this is the scenario that we wanted to solve.

Comment: @dellboy you can use e.g. REST API or you can have a client node in your web service, initialized at start and used to interact with your Ignite cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alamar